# I am not sure if I used the right hypotheses test or made the right conclusions, could you give me a feedback?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have just finish a basic statistic course and I decided to apply what I learned in a small project using the wine quality dataset. I am not sure if what I did was correct, so if possible, I would really appreciate a feedback. This is the jupyter notebook from my project https://github.com/felipeDamasceno/Portifolio-ciencia-de-dados/tree/main/Wine%20quality

EDIT 1:

As requested in the comments, I am going to write more about my test and conclusions. What worried me was that I did tests in order to showcase what I know as a portfolio and It might end up showing the opposite, in case that what I did is wrong. I thought the results on my tests would be different so I would like a feedback, if possible. My dataset is the wine quality dataset, I joined the white wine and the red wine and my dataset is like the image bellow.

[image: img1]

My first question: Is there a dependence between the wine type and its quality? In order to answer this question I used a chi-square test for independence, because we are dealing with nominal variables and the observations about the quality of the wine are independent.

That is how I coded:

```
myCrosstable = pd.crosstab(wine['quality'], wine['type'])
chiVal, pVal, df, exp = stats.chi2_contingency(myCrosstable)
r = len(myCrosstable.index)
c = len(myCrosstable.columns)
n = myCrosstable.to_numpy().sum()
V = (chiVal / (n*(min(r,c) - 1)))**0.5 # Cramer's V
```

My results were p value = 8.66434779598271e-23, Cramer's V = 0.133932872759777 and degrees of freedom = 1.

My conclusions: The p-value is smaller than 0.05 (our alpha level), so we can reject the null hypotheses and say that there is a dependable relationship between the wine type and it's quality. The strength of this relationship is small according to the result from Cramér's V though. Therefore, even though there is a relationship, it is not strong.

My second question: Is there a difference between the alcohol used and the wine quality separate by good (  quality > 6) and bad ( quality <= 6)? I am using t-test for independent samples because we are testing only two variables (good and bad), the dataset is a sample and the observations are independent from each other. The test is a two tailed test.

My code:

```
t, p = stats.ttest_ind(wine['alcohol'][wine['bin quality']== 1],
    wine['alcohol'][wine['bin quality']== 0])
r = stats.pearsonr(wine['alcohol'].to_numpy(), wine['bin quality'].to_numpy())
r_squared = r[0]**2
```

My results: p value = 1.1796681024880703e-235,
r = 0.39048601262473726, r p value 1.1796681025011215e-235 and
r squared = 0.15247932605556647.

My conclusion: There is a difference between the amount of alcohol used compare to the wine quality. 15,25% of this difference in alcohol can be explained by the wine quality and the relationship between the two variables is positive correlated and statistically significant. The relationship strength between the variables is weak to moderated.

It is important to say that by stats I am referring to scipy.stats. For more info you can look at my notebook: https://github.com/felipeDamasceno/Portifolio-ciencia-de-dados/tree/main/Wine%20quality

Comment: please can you post what specific part of the code you applied hypothesis testing? write more about what are you doing and your conclusions in this way we can help you. your question need more context for help you.